# Making the Google Maps API non readable

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, google-maps

Our former developers created this code below. However, when it renders on our site, it displays the API key. Is there a better way to hide the API key while still enlisting the script to be executed?

```
wp_enqueue_script('hw-google-map','https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=APIKEYTHATISPUBLIC', array('jquery'), 1.1, false);
```

Comment: This is the correct way of sending a request to the Google Maps API. Any security restrictions would be applied within the Google account itself.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't obfuscate/hide the code, you can restrict access by domain: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices